# Why does my email jump to something that isn't the next email when I delete something in Outlook 2016?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

Outlook 2016 has been acting funny for quite some time on my desktop.

There is a minior annoyance that when I delete an email it jumps to some place mid bottom when I delete an item.

Normally, it just moves to the next email instead of moving way, way to the bottom.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Please go to ***File > Options > Mail > Other*** and check the "***After moving or deleting an open item***" option as shown in the below figure view, and choose ***Open the next item***.

[image]

If the above doesn't help, considering the influence of some views, please try a command to reset the view settings: win+R> type: ***outlook /cleanviews***. (This command will delete all custom view settings. If you need to keep other view settings, please remember to back up.)

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If it is useful, would you mind marking the helpful post as an answer? Which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.